# How to find if a hotfix has been installed MS Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-update

I'm doing a comparison of our staging and production environments and have created a list of hotfixes. It shows which server has the hotfix and which server it is missing.

I can search for the hotfix via the KB# and install it directly, but I am curious as to why the missing update does not appear when doing a windows update search.

The other question I have is I'm not quite sure how cumulative updates come in with regards to this. If I install a cumulative update that came after this hotfix was released, should this update be disregareded? Can I still determine if this hotfix was installed or should I then be comparing cumulative updates at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly what you said. Cumulative updates are "cumulative," they contain all prior updates.

Windows 7 and newer and equivalent server OSes have all changed to an update "roll up" method of patch management. This is an effort to reduce the burden of updating a newly installed OS.

Often, you can google for the monthly update roll up or the individual patch and find what roll ups added which patches. But keep in mind the current roll up contains all previous security and quality updates.

Here's a blog from Microsoft to help explain some of it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/10/07/more-on-windows-7-and-windows-8-1-servicing-changes/

You should change your process from looking for specific hot fixes to making sure the OS is at a certain update rollup level. Namely "Month/year" as each roll up is released monthly.